# include file on file included on file with relative path: working only sometimes

Tags: php, path, include, require

My site structure is like this.

HTDOCS folder: `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/`

ADMIN folder: `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/admin/`

EDIT ADMIN folder: `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/admin/edit`

HTACCESS protected folder: `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/admin/flock/`

TEST folder : `/WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/`

**SITUATION 1**

The following script1.php is placed in the Admin folder:

```
<?php
require_once 'flock/sql.php' or die("Error");
?>
```

Now I include script1.php on scripttest.php placed in the Edit admin folder:

```
<?php
require_once '../script1.php' or die ("Error");
?>
```

*It works without any error.*

**SITUATION 2**

Now I have script2.php placed in the Test folder:

```
<?php
require_once '../admin/flock/sql.php' or die("Error");
?>
```

And call it from scripttest.php placed always in the Edit admin folder:

```
<?php
require_once '../../test/script2.php';
?>
```

*And it won't work anymore. Those are the errors:*

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]:
Unable to access ../admin/flock/sql.php in /WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/script2.php
on line 2

Warning: require_once(../admin/flock/sql.php) [function.require-once]:
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/script2.php
on line 2

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required
'../admin/flock/sql.php' (include_path='/usr/local/lib/php/:/WEB/mysite/') in
/WEB/mysite/htdocs/test/script2.php on line 2.
```

**The two situation are the same thing. Aren't they?
Why is situation two not working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths are like relative directions, if I tell to take two steps forward and one step to the left you are only going to end up at the right place if you start at the same place every time.  The starting place with php is where ever the execution of the main script kicks off.  To make life sane you need to establish a couple of waypoints that you can include relative to.

Some common ones are:

1. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` - This is  your domains root directory (the filesystem path that relates to going to http://www.mysite.com/)
2. `__DIR__` - a constant that is the directory of the current file.

Usually it is a good idea to create a constant that establishes a location that makes sense for your project... for example.

```
// site_config.php -- located in a config directory next to your document root.
define("COMMON_INCLUDES", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes");
```

the site_config.php would then be included in all of your pages by:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../config/site_config.php");
```

and when you needed an asset out of the includes you would then say

```
include(COMMON_INCLUDES."/header.php");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But if I understand it right this:
`include(COMMON_INCLUDES."/header.php");`
will be the same as: `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php`. So what if `header.php` is on another directory... I'll have to use again relative path?! Isn't then simplier to use always `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pathtothefile/file.php'`and stop using relative path?

Comment: it would be much safer. Adding the abstraction of the constant that I outlined is a good method to use say if you have a dev version of the site that for some reason or another can't live on the site root.  Then for that one you can change the constant to `define("INCLUDE_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/mydevsite/includes");` it provides more flexibility when staging the site in different environments.

Comment: on a side note another thing that this method (establishing a static point to include off of) does for you is guards you against the `chdir` command. The moment one of these crops up in one of your includes it bakes all of the relative paths you define after it.

Comment: Ok I understand. What remains unclear to me is: if I have all the site on the document_root, will the `define` be useless because is the same as using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

If yes, should I use anyway the `define` so that if in the future I'll need to change something I'll have only to change the definition on `define`?

And at least: everytime I include a file I should use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` function (or the `define` I set for it) ana never the relative path? Why I read in the past that using relative paths is better in case of changing a server/etc.?

Comment: the define would in fact effectively redundant, but if you use it anyway it will ease moving thing around in the future and on the php side should make it where you only have to change that one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same. The relative path in this case in based from the location of the file that kicked off the include chain. Use the `__DIR__` constant to make the path be relative to the file where each include is called:

```
<?php
// will evaluate to /WEB/mysite/htdocs/admin/flock/sql.php always
require_once __DIR__ . '/flock/sql.php' or die("Error");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If the relative path is based from the location of the file thatkicked off the include chain, then this file is `scripttest.php`: if `scripttest.php` is on `/admin/edit/` and `script1.php` is on `/admin/` then when `script1.php` runs `require_once 'flock/sql.php'`, if the relative path as you wrote is based on `scripttest.php` it will call `'/admin/edit/flock/sql.php'`, but in fact it is calling the right path `'/admin/flock/sql.php'`, where `sql.php` is!

Comment: No `script1.php' is on `/admin/` that is the point of where everything was kicked off. so anything that script1.php includes either directly or indirectly will be relative to that path. So when script1 imports flock/sql.php then it will be `/admin/flock/sql.php` if script1.php includes scripttest.php which includes flock/sql.php then that again will refer to the same location.

Comment: But `scripttest.php` includes `script1.php` and `script2.php` so the path starts from `scripttest.php`? Or are all the path starting from the first script which includes something??